# How to get value of dropdown menu in semantic ui?

Tags: html, jquery, semantic-ui

I have this code but I don't know how to get selected value.Where should i give id value for this list?

```
<div class="ui compact menu">
    <div class="ui simple dropdown item">Question
        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
        <div id="question" class="menu">
            <div id="type" class="item" data-value="mcsc">Multiple Choice Single Correct</div>
            <div id="type" class="item" data-value="mcmc">Multiple Choice Multiple Correct</div>
            <div id="type" class="item" data-value="numerical">Numerical</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 30):

You must use something like this:

```
$('#idDropDown').dropdown('get value');
```

I hope that helps you.

Docs for this can be found in last table here: 
https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#/usage

Comment: @nicolasie how do I get this information by documentation I am new to web development, any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

`$('#DropDownID').find(":selected").val();`

Answer (score 1):

I've search for the best this one is little bit better than other functions. It 100% works in proper use.

```
$('#dropdown-id').dropdown('setting', 'onChange', function(){

});
```